Unable to retrieve DS160 form
I entered a DS160 form 5 months ago and did not submit.
I also booked an interview slot using the DS160 form numbers. Now I'm unable to retrieve the DS160 form. How can I retrieve it?
Thank you.

Your DS160 application and its data is stored for only 30 days, so you better create a new one! See the govt website for more information clearly mentioning 30 days https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/ds-160-faqs.html
